# traversing an object tree

Tags: python

I'm trying to find information on different ways to traverse an object tree in python.
I don't know much about the language in general yet, so any suggestions/techniques would be welcome.

Thanks so much
jml

Comment: you should begin by explaining what you mean by object tree. Are you speaking of introspection ?

Comment: i found out how to do it.  basically myobject.membername1.membername2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out how to do it.  basically myobject.membername1.membername2

Comment: i think the type(myobj.someparam) trick was the most useful to me, as it helps one find out how to address a given portion of an object.  this was the most confusing point for me originally; that a single list object (for ex) could contain a number of differing data types.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module. It has functions for accessing/listing all kinds of object information.

Comment: This is inapplicable. OP is really trying to extract data from a deserialized JSON file, not figure out things about strange objects at runtime.

Comment: ok; i also found out about the help(someobject) functionality.  very handy

Comment: mike; you are right.  i found out more from just printing type(someobject["membername"])

Comment: Well, who could have known that. The question makes it look like the problem is traversing of unknown objects.